# Vim : How to insert a / after certain length in multiple line

Tags: vim

Here is following piece of text (a c++ code) which I am trying to edit in vim,

```
#define MACRO(X)                    /
{                                   /
    if(x)
    {
       "some action performed here"
    }
}
```

I want to complete this  macro syntax by introducing / at each  line. For aesthetic reasons I want the / to be aligned at same line length like how it is done for first two lines. How to achieve this in  a single or few Vim commands. Assume that macro is very big in line count and I cant manually introduce *space* and / at every line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I am confused that the "macro" you meant in your question is a vim macro or your function named "MACRO(X)"?

To solve the problem you need `set ve=all` read `:h 've'` for detail.

If you meant the "macro" is a vim one, that is, you want to extend an existing vim macro, it is hard to tell how to do that. That's because we cannot see the existing macro, what does it do.

I list here two ways to do it, one is using a vim macro, you can put it into your existing one and test if it is required. The other one is using `:normal` command.

- Assume that you've `set ve=all`
- Assume that you want to add a `/` on column `50`

### vim macro

First record a macro `a`:

```
qa050lr/jq
```

Then you can replay it x times, e.g. `99@a`

[image]

### normal command

```
%norm! 50lr\
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry @kent for not being clear. It is a c++ code which I am trying to edit. Consider my example as a piece of text that I want to modify in vim editor. So nothing to do with VIM macro. 
Can you please edit your answer with this info. 
I have also edited my question to avoid confusion

Comment: @KarthickS removing those parts is easy. pls check if my answer helped you. It does provide solutions

Answer (score 1):

Two more ways to do the same thing.

1. If `set ve=all` or `set ve=block` using blockwise-visual mode.

   ```
   $<C-V>6jr/
   ```

That is, go to an existing "/" at top line. Then enter blockwise-visual mode. Then extend selection downwards. Then replace everything with "/"

2. Using just `:s`

   ```
   1,7s/$/\=repeat(' ', 49 - strlen(getline('.')))..nr2char(47)
   ```

That is, substitute "end of lines" 1 through 7 with an expression (variable number of spaces followed by slash).